# .NET Challenge redirects back to same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, cookies

Im trying to learn more about adding external authentication to a .net application im writing(Using razor pages). Im following a tutorial on youtube, but i get a different result from what he is getting.
When im trying to authenticate with google, the Challenge method redirects the browser so i can authenticate with google(or single signin if im already logged on), then it for some reason redirects me right back to the page where im calling the challenge method and it goes in a loop.
If i close the application and run it again, i can see that i got a cookie created and that i got the claims from google. What i dont understand is why it redirects in a loop.

The flow is as follows: User goes to login page -> Login page has hyperlink to google authentication page(called Google.cshtml in my project) -> The OnGet method in Google.cshtml.cs return Challenge(schemename for google in program.cs).
I Created a page called Callback that the program should redirect to after google authentication is done, but when i add a break-point i see that it never gets redirected(only redirects back to google in a loop).

Any help on understanding the problem is greatly appriciated. This is my code:

Hyperlink in Login.cshtml that sends user to page for google authentication:

```
<a  asp-page="Google" asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
   <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
</a>
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
    .AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    })
    //.AddCookie("temp")
    .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "Omitted in this post";
        options.ClientSecret = "Omitted in this post";
        //options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
        //options.SignInScheme = "temp";
    })
    .AddMicrosoftAccount("Microsoft", options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "omitted in this post";
        options.ClientSecret = "Omitted in this post";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
        //options.SignInScheme = "temp";
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();

app.Run();
```

Google.cshtml.cs

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class Google : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ReturnUrl != null)
        {
            if (!Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid return url. fail!");
            }   
        }

        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Page("Callback"),
            Items =
            {
                {"uru", "/index"},
                {"scheme", "Google"}
            }
        };
        return Challenge(props,"Google");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem for anyone wondering. I had to add a / to the parameter in Url.Page() making it Url.Page("/Callback"). Weird that the guy from the tutorial didnt get the same error from this considering he only wrote Callback without forward slash